# Variable is being updated in all same multiple components used in root component angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I created a child component and used multiple times in the root component. Now the issue is, when I update the variable value in one of the component, the change is reflecting in all other same components. How can I stop it? I am not able to understand what is happening here!

Please find the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nm3jqw) for the issue

**root component html** in the root component

```
<hello></hello>
<hello></hello>
```

**hello component html**

```
<div class="green-box" *ngIf="green; else red"></div>
<ng-template #red>
  <div class="red-box"></div>
</ng-template>
<button (click)='changeColor()'>Change Color</button>
```

**hello component ts**

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  green: boolean = true;

  constructor(
    private changeService: ChangeService,
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeService.change$.subscribe((data: boolean) => {
      this.green = data;
    });
  }

  changeColor() {
    this.changeService.changeColor(!this.green);
  }
}
```

**change service ts**

```
export class ChangeService {

  public changeSubjcet = new Subject();
  public change$ = this.changeSubjcet.asObservable();

  changeColor( value ) {
    this.changeSubjcet.next( value );
  }

}
```

Comment: This is the definition of a singleton service. There exists one and *only* one instance of the observable `change$` in your app. So if you modify it somewhere it'll be reflected on every individual subscription.

Comment: Got your point @MichaelD . How can I resolve this issue? So, the change should be applied in respective component only

Comment: Just don’t use a service and set the value directly on component scope..?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment

> This is the definition of a [singleton service](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). There exists one and
>   *only* one instance of the observable `change$` in your app. So if you
>   modify it somewhere it'll be reflected on every individual
>   subscription.

If you wish to have instance specific variables, just create member variables that aren't related to any singleton services.

hello.component.ts

```js
export class HelloComponent {
  green: boolean = true;

  changeColor() {
    this.green = !this.green;
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fqwzu5).

If you're new to Angular, I'd also recommend you to go through [this](https://angular.io/tutorial) tutorial. It introduces some of the basics.